# I have data of some movies and their subtitles.I want to classify them based on their ratings

Tags: classification, nlp, svm, pca, lda

I will convert the subtitles into vectors and use them as features to classify the movies into different categories based on their ratings.The problem that I am facing is my feature vector is much much larger compared to the number of examples I have. I would like to know what should the size of my tailing data set be to use LDA,PCA,SVM and naive Bayes.Would 10 movies per category be sufficient?

Comment: As far as I know, SVM should work fine, even if you have small numbers of records per category. But I would try to use more abstract categories. If possible, try to use not more than 10 different categories.

Comment: Can you please tell me why you think svm works fine?

Comment: _"Geometrically, the SVM modeling algorithm works by con-
structing a separating hyperplane with the maximal margin. Compared
with other standard classifiers, SVM is more accurate on moderately
imbalanced data."_ - [Tang, Chawla (2009): SVMs Modeling for Highly Imbalanced Classification.](https://www3.nd.edu/~dial/publications/tang2009svms.pdf)